# Animating plugin when switching or tabbing through form fields

Tags: forms, animation, plugins, field

I'm looking for a jQuery or so plugin that shows a quick animation between form fields, when you click or tab through them.

Comment: Bump. Anyone? I think I saw this plugin a few years ago. It's quite old already but I hope someone can help me find it, or find something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the plugin you're referring to is "Flying Focus" http://n12v.com/focus-transition/ is where it was originally posted. https://github.com/NV/flying-focus is the git repo.